# How can I append a media query to a <style> tag?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, import, css-animations

I'm using Skrollr for my Parallax animations and via Skrollr.stylesheets, I can use Parallax keyframes, instead of writing them inline.

To have the plugin use external stylesheets for the keyframes, it's using AJAX to search the stylesheets, imported via `<link>`. Therefor, you need to host your website somewhere or have a local server to see those in action.

In order to work locally without a local server, best way is to have your keyframes within a `<style>` tag, within your `head` of the page.

However, using parallax keyframes on a mobile device is devastating for the performance. Therefor, I would like to have the parallax keyframes only to be executed on devices with `min-width:40.063em`.

Too bad, I can't use a `@media query` on `<style>` tags.

A sample of a piece of keyframe:

```
        #slide-1 .bcg, #slide-3 .bcg, #slide-4 .bcg, #slide-5 .bcg, #portfolio .bcg, #meerPortfolio .bcg {
        -skrollr-animation-name:bg150pxUp;
    }

    @-skrollr-keyframes bg150pxUp {
        bottom {
            background-position:50% 0px;
        }

        top-bottom {
            background-position:50% -150px
        }
    }
```

Who knows a way to use media queries/Have the above CSS keyframes loaded on devices with at least a min width viewport of 40.063 em - And not use something like `<link>`?

Thanks!

`apologies if it's a little incomprehensible`

Comment: Can't you just use media queries inside the style tag ?

Comment: Please see my comment on the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use `@media query` inside of a `<style>` tag -

```
<style type="text/css">

@media all and (min-width: 40.063 em) { /* Change to whatever media query you require */


#slide-1 .bcg, #slide-3 .bcg, #slide-4 .bcg, #slide-5 .bcg, #portfolio .bcg, #meerPortfolio .bcg {
    -skrollr-animation-name:bg150pxUp;
}

@-skrollr-keyframes bg150pxUp {
    bottom {
        background-position:50% 0px;
    }

    top-bottom {
        background-position:50% -150px
    }
}
}

</style>
```

Comment: Strangely, that doesn't work. On both devices equal to the requirement and not (so both desktop and mobile) the styles are not appended. I'm quickly taking a shower, I will test some things and report back. But as far as I know, it ain't working, because of the @ statements from the skrollr key frames..

Comment: Nope, can't verify it's working. Website remains exactly the same, no parallax. When I remove the @media line, everything is working again.

Comment: You absolutely can use CSS Media Queries within a `<style>` tag in the  `<head>`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries - Your problem is likely caused because of a conflict here.

Comment: I am having this same problem. Need a style in a media query based on a calculated height, so I'm using javascript to generate CSS. But the style is not applied. If I remove the @media, it works fine. Did you end up being able to fix this two years ago?